# Simple GridView to view pics in android

Tags: android, xml, android-gridview

### I have GridView that displayes image from a JSON

**[Image]**

[image]

*My xml for grid view is* ::

**restaurant_desc_photos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

**grid_view_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to make make changes so that i could reflect my output as ::

[image]

Horizontal scrolling is also important here

### Any IDEAS

***Thanks***

Comment: Create dynamic gridview inside horizontal scrollView.

Comment: Can you show edit the code as your answer ...

Comment: @Unicorn what you want exactly???

Comment: I am trying to edit xml(restaurant_desc_photos.xml) to obtain horizontal scroll view ! as shown in figure !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to do it is use two way grid view library use this following link for library
https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

1) add that library to the project

2) change the package names accordingly in the xml layout where you will be inserting the horizontal scroll view
snippet:

```
   <com.future.android.app.library.slidinggridview.TwoWayGridView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/fragment_product_twgv_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:cacheColorHint="#ffe8e8e8"
    app:columnWidth="300dp"
    app:horizontalSpacing="10.0dip"
    app:numColumns="auto_fit"
    app:numRows="2"
    app:rowHeight="290dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
    app:scrollDirectionPortrait="vertical"
    app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    app:verticalSpacing="10.0dip" />
```

you can set the number of columns accordingly and width and height too.

Comment: Thanks for the source .........But It might require API16 ........ is it not possible to achieve this in lower level api like 8 ? ... i am just wondering !